# Can we specify the language to the faker library of python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python-2.7 and newbie to fake-factory library refer to [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory/0.2).
Following is my code-

```
from faker import Factory
fake = Factory.create()
print fake.paragraphs(nb=2)
```

And output is-

```
Fugiat ut praesentium quas a itaque tenetur repellat. Doloribus veniam autem est ipsa facere ducimus nam.
[u'Magni eveniet temporibus dolore nesciunt porro. Omnis quidem magni a repellendus. Nostrum amet nihil minima laborum.', u'Reiciendis molestiae labore facilis nemo numquam minus consequatur. Accusamus amet explicabo eos ad. Itaque autem illum quasi amet iste molestiae. Iure dolorum ipsa nisi architecto veniam architecto. Eveniet iure non consequuntur earum laudantium perferendis recusandae quas.']
```

Since this language is unknown to me , is there a way to specify the language in faker so that the paragraph comes in English.
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you *can* specify a locale provider to the faker library when you use `Factory.create`, by passing a local as a parameter. But without passing a locale, it defaults back to the `en_US` locale you may want anyways (*[see the other English ones](http://fake-factory.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#localization)*), so that is not your issue.

Your issue here is that `.paragraphs` is in [`fakers.provide.lorem`](http://fake-factory.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locales/en_US.html?highlight=paragraphs#faker-providers-lorem), which uses the very common "lorem ipsum" dummy-text used in printing and typing. The whole point of a fake paragraph is that there is nothing in it except placeholder dummy-text, so it is unclear to me why you would want to *understand* a `fake.paragraphs` - the answer is you cannot.

Comment: Thank-you that was indeed helpful. I just wanted a text data randomly generated since I am trying to learn text-analysis. I wanted to create random text hence I was searching for something like this.

Comment: @PallaviJoshi I see, yes you won't get any sort of _reasonable_ randmoly generated text from `.paragraphs`, unfortunately. I would advise maybe finding a nice source to download or scrape some random text from.

Comment: Scraping is done looking for a text file data may be csv or delimiter  separated text which will make me learn on how to handle minute things. Although thanks a lot :)